# Forge viewer shadows are not working properly in large models

Tags: three.js, webgl, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using forge viewer version 7, i have followed  the shadow & lighting based on this https://github.com/wallabyway/adding-shadows

but it not working when i am using large model's. it's only shows the patch of the ground shadow.
[shadow issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m3QP.png)
any one having the solutution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Use webGL 1.0 path.
ForgeViewer v7.9 activated the webGL 2.0 render pipeline, which broke the shadow map feature.
The workaround is this:

```
viewer.start(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {
                webglInitParams: {
                    useWebGL2: false
                }
            });
```

There is a fix to this Forge-Viewer regression, on it's way. ETA not yet known.

**Details:**
The exponential shadow maps feature inside Forge-Viewer, is experimental, hence why I did not publish a blog post on this, and just kept it as a GitHub post.  And as you can see, the feature broke in Forge-Viewer v7.4 and above.  The viewer team, have no roadmap to fix it, but I can put in a request.

**The bug**
You are also correct in noticing geometry missing from the shadow map. This is due to the nature of progressive rendering.  The shadow map renderer has a small budget in render-batches.  If the scene is too big, and progressive rendering kicks in, then the shadow map renderer will not completely render the scene to the shadow map, and hence cause missing shadows.

It was because of this limitation, that the shadow feature was not released.

**Workarounds**

- Try turning off "progressive rendering", in the settings.  This may cause bad FPS for large scenes, but should fix the missing shadows
- Recreate the model, to something smaller, so that progressive rendering is not needed.

Sorry this is not more helpful.
Cheers
Michael